# How to sniff packets on Mac OS 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, ssl, https, packet-sniffers

I'm developing a website that uses SSL (connction to https) and I want to confirm that all the data sent is encrypted. Could anyone give me a good free packet sniffer on Mac OS that I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's not as slick as Wireshark, but OS X has a built-in command line tool for capturing and displaying packets:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -s0 -ien0 port 80
```

(the `-A` flag makes it display the packets' contents as text, `-s0` makes it capture entire packets not just the headers, `-ien0` makes it capture on the first ethernet interface (generally, the wireless is en1), and `port 80` makes it only capture traffic to/from port 80 (see the man page for more options for capture patterns.)

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget Packet Peeper, WireShark is not so nice on Mac.

http://packetpeeper.org/

Comment: Can you elaborate why wireshark is not so nice on Mac?

Comment: @DanEsparza GTK+ (with default theme) on OS X obviously looks uglier than native interface.

Comment: @ivanzoid Agreed.  It's such a mess that after I installed (and winced) I uninstalled.

Comment: Packet Peeper appears to be abandoned (no updates since 2009), but still works fine for me. Far better UI than Wirewhark, and does TCP stream reassembly (the main feature I miss in tcpdump).

Comment: Packet Peeper doesn't work with virtual devices created with `rvictl` (Remote Virtual Interface Tool)..

Comment: There has been updates made in 2014 - so its still alive and kicking it seems :)

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark, or, Lion comes with one built in.  Find it at /System/Library/CoreServices/Wi-Fi Diagnostics.  I prefer Wireshark.

Comment: Given that Wi-Fi Diagnostics just writes out a pcap file, and does nothing to help you read it, Wireshark, or even tcpdump, is preferable for Mr. Smith's purposes.  (I also don't know whether it'll capture on non-Wi-Fi interfaces, if that's what he wants.)